# `Control + Alt + Tab` does not show the top bar in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

In Gnome 2, when an application was fullscreen, `Control + Alt + Tab` would let you select either the top bar or the bottom bar (AFAIK, they are also called "panels").  In Gnome 3, the same keyboard shortcut lets you select only the bottom bar.  How can you show the top bar?

EDIT: I am experiencing the same problem with Gnome Classic.

EDIT2: The problem is that when applications go fullscreen, they cover both panels, and I can only make Gnome show the bottom one.

EDIT3: I have found that both `Super` and `Super+S` enter the Overview, thus showing the top bar in Gnome Shell.

Comment: Which gnome shell version are you using? The extension [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) supports having a shortcut to hide the top bar, but the bar will automatically be hidden most of the time.